# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB in union query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have some Oracle query where i need to use `CLOB_AGG` function because when i used string_agg i got string buffer error (more than 4000 characters).
The problem is that when i use query separately it works but when i do the union.

I get:

> inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB error.

```
SELECT
  A.EVENT_ID,
  clob_agg(CAL.CALENDAR_DT) AS CALENDAR_DAYS
FROM
  TABLE1 A,
  CALENDAR CAL
WHERE
AND CAL.EVENT_ID(+) = A.EVENT_ID
GROUP BY
  A.EVENT_ID
UNION
SELECT
  B.SUB_EVENT_CD,
  CLOB_AGG(CALSUB.CALENDAR_DT) AS CALENDAR_DAYS
FROM
  TABLE1 A,
  TABLE1 B,
  RSS_CALENDAR CALSUB
WHERE
AND A.EVENT_ID             = B.EVENT_ID
AND CALSUB.SUB_EVENT_ID(+) = B.SUB_EVENT_ID
GROUP BY
  A.EVENT_ID,
  B.SUB_EVENT_ID
```

Comment: Try `union all` instead of `union`.

Comment: Remove that `AND`  near to the `WHERE` clause..

Comment: You have a syntax error in individual SQL itself, so it won't run without UNION too.

Comment: Use `union all`. `Union` combine two sets and try to eliminate duplicate. But compare CLOB is impossible. 
`select 1 from dual where  empty_clob() =  empty_clob();` return the same  ORA.

Comment: It works with union all .Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

There were a few issues with your code. You needed a `UNION ALL` rather than a `UNION` and you had two `AND`'s straight after a `WHERE`.

I have also replaced your joins with standard notation explicit joins rather than using join operators.

```
SELECT A.EVENT_ID, clob_agg(CAL.CALENDAR_DT) AS CALENDAR_DAYS
FROM TABLE1 A
LEFT OUTER JOIN CALENDAR CAL ON CAL.EVENT_ID = A.EVENT_ID
GROUP BY A.EVENT_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT B.SUB_EVENT_CD, CLOB_AGG(CALSUB.CALENDAR_DT) AS CALENDAR_DAYS
FROM TABLE1 A
INNER JOIN TABLE1 B ON A.EVENT_ID = B.EVENT_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN RSS_CALENDAR CALSUB ON CALSUB.SUB_EVENT_ID = B.SUB_EVENT_ID
GROUP BY A.EVENT_ID, B.SUB_EVENT_ID
```